# Linked Server from SQL Server 2014 to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am trying to create a Linked Server from an office based SQL Server Installation to a remote MySQL database. I have tried doing this using the SQL Server Wizard as well as the T-SQL code. The code I am using at the moment is shown below:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='MYSQL', @srvproduct='MYSQL', @provider='MSDASQL',
@datasrc='TestConnection', @provstr='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};SERVER=111.111.111.111;Port=111;USER=user;PASSWORD=password;OPTION=3;DATABASE=TestDatabase;'
```

I have replaced all the sensitive data with test examples.

I had created an ODBC Connection to the MySQL Database locally from my PC and tested it and the connection works fine. I even use the same details in my MySQL Workbench so I know there are no issues with the connection details.

When I run the above code it says that the connection has been created but when I navigate to it in SQL Server I get the error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of the OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL", (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:7399)

I was under the impression really as I had set up the connection in the ODBC with the correct username and password, I really shouldn't need to include them in the above statement but I have tried with and without but with no success. Does the issue have something to do with setting up a SQL Server login to allow all of the above to happen?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly answer your question, but I'll post my connection setup notes and script - maybe helps. IIRC MySQL driver version was somehow important.

```
/*
MySQL ODBC driver version 5.13 (install on SQL server)
System DSN name: my_web (create on SQL server, configure, test connectivity)
ODBC options: (leave default)
MSDASQL provider options (set in SSMS):
    Nested queries
    Level zero
    Allow inprocess
    Supports Like
*/

-- run next to drop linked server definition named 'my_web_linked', if required
--exec master.dbo.sp_dropserver N'my_web_linked', 'droplogins'

exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'my_web_linked', 
    @srvproduct=N'MySQL', 
    @provider=N'MSDASQL', 
    @datasrc='my_web'

exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname=N'my_web_linked',
    @useself=N'False',
    @locallogin=NULL,
    @rmtuser=N'MySQL user name here',
    @rmtpassword=N'MySQL password value here'

-- run next to test connection - assuming you have table named test on mysql db
--select * from my_web_linked...test
```

Comment: Hi Arvo, thanks for posting your sample script, I replaced details where I needed to based on my setup but unfortunately I am still unable to make the connection.  I have also tried following the instructions listed on this web site :- [link](http://bradmarsh.net/index.php/2008/11/12/setting-up-linked-servers-between-mysql-and-mssql/) but nothing seems to work at the moment, any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install, configure and test ODBC connection on SQL server machine? Linked server connection is made from SQL server, not from client PC. Is your SQL server 32bit or 64bit one?

Comment: Hi Arvo, thanks for the reply, yes the ODBC is installed and configured on the SQL Server machine and the SQL Server is a 64bit one.  Thanks Phil

Comment: Then ODBC driver has to be 64bit one as well. About MySQL user rights on MySQL server - does it have access to `information_schema` views? You can try `select * from openquery(my_web_linked, 'select * from test')` also - for some drivers and conditions, 4-part table names do not work.

Comment: Hi Arvo, I am using the 64bit ODBC driver on my server,  When I go to test my connection I get the original error message, I haven't tried running a direct openquery call to the mysql from sql due to not being able to test the linked server successfully, hope that makes sense and thanks again.

Comment: Does ODBC, System DSN, connection test give you OLEDB error message??? Sorry about asking similar things many times over; there can be many slightly different problems. One thing is ODBC connectivity test - when this fails, then most likely problem is in network configration or MySQL access limitations (your SQL server IP may not be allowed). Another thing is SQL server connection failure to linked server - this can be some configuration error or inability to check MySQL table structure (not while using `openquery`, only for direct query).

Comment: Hi Arvo, no worries at all please ask as many questions as you need to, the help is much appreciated.  In answer to your question the testing of the ODBC. System DSN on the server comes back fine with no error messages at all, this is what is confusing me really as there seems to be no reason why it is not working as it should.  You mention a SQL Server connection failure to linked server, though it may not be related, we do have an active directory sever set up as a linked server and that is working fine.

Comment: Try `openquery()` then.

Comment: Hi Arvo, thanks for all the replies. I sat down with the IT manager on Friday to have another look a this as I thought it might of been just an issue with the permissions on the accounts that I was using to create the connection or even on my own sql server account.  After some messing about we decided to try and create the ODBC connection in the 32bit ODBC just to see if we got the same issue and for a bizarre reason it started working though everything is 64bit....as you have been the most helpful in fixing this problem I will mark your first  answer as the correct one....thanks again!!